# Error running Gradle while trying to setup Firebase with Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

Getting the following error while trying to run new flutter app with Firebase

```
Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "...\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
```

I have followed instructions at https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup to the letter.

google-services.json is at android/app folder

in app/build.gradle i have

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
}
```

}

and in project build.gradle dependencies

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
```

and at the bottom

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Play services Gradle plugin
```

pubspec.yaml has

```
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9
```

The app is registered with correct name at Firebase console as android app.

- I tried with different versions of com.android.tools.build:gradle and com.google.gms:google-services
- flutter doctor shows no errors
- I deleted user/.gradle/caches/ folders

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Maadhav-Sharma's answer i got it working with following fixes. Problems is with AndroidX compatibility even for new Flutter projects with compileSdkVersion 28 that should AndroiX compatible. More info: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility

Make a new project first.

In android/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
}
```

In android/gradle/wrapper/gradle.properties, append

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

In android/app/build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {


    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true // This was needed to get FireStore to work
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1' // This was needed to get FireStore to work

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```