# Unable to add firebase to android (flutter)

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, flutter

I have been trying to resolve this issue since two days and I have also tried the solutions already present at Stack Overflow regarding this problem but did not succeed. 
All the steps that I have followed are from ***Add Firebase to your Android app guide (The steps by Firebase Official)***

**PROJECT-LEVEL Build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**APP-LEVEL Build.gradle:**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.loginapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Pubspec.yaml File:**

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+9

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

**Gradle-wrapper.properties:**

```
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
```

**ERROR:**

```
PS D:\flutterworks\bhund> flutter run
Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with
"--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                              5.1s
Resolving dependencies...
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "D:\flutterworks\bhund\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

  Command: D:\flutterworks\bhund\android\gradlew.bat app:properties


Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
PS D:\flutterworks\bhund>
```

Comment: Please post your errors and code as text instead of images because that is far more convenient to work with.

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58294378/error-running-gradle-while-trying-to-setup-firebase-with-flutter

Comment: you need to migrate your project to androidX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and could not migrate to Androidx manually.
Note that it is necessary for projects to now be in Androidx if you want to use Firebase, or it may cause more problems later.

Step 1: In your project level gradle change:

```
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
```

to:

```
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
```

Usually after this step, your project will run fine, but it is import to migrate to AndroidX right now and not cause further errors while using Firebase.

Step 2: Once this is done, just make a new project with Androidx settings, you can do this by opening the flutter_console.bat and navigating to your desired folder then run:

```
    flutter create --androidx your_project_name
```

on your flutter console.

Step 3: Navigate to your new project > android > gradle.properties and check if it has these two lines:

```
    android.useAndroidX=true
    android.enableJetifier=true
```

This means that the project has migrated to Androidx.

Step 4: Finally, move all your code from the old project to the new flutter project along with all the dependencies and plugins you may have added in the old project. (Including dependency in Step 1)

Comment: Thanks for making it simple !

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is just go to your project level build and change your **classpath dependencies** and **kotlin version** as below.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

To add AndroidX in your flutter project, go to **android package** > **gradle.properties**

Inside gradle.properties add two lines.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

This might work for you.

Comment: Do I have to also change this line of code **distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip**  in  Gradle-wrapper.properties.

Comment: This what I got after applying your suggestion : **Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1**

Comment: Yes, you need to update the following line also. distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip

Comment: I have to convert 5.4.1 into which version ?

Comment: Just go to your android package > gradle package > wrapper package 

Inside gradle-wrapper.properties replase this line distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip with your current distributionUrl.